# How can updating a link result in sharing confidential information in Microsoft PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have a Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 file that contains a few linked object. Each time I open it I get the following warning:

[image]

How can updating a link result in sharing confidential information?

I use Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

When it says "Links" it means any linked files.  Anything downloaded from the Internet can be interfered with, and used to break in.  Powerpoint is defaulting to the safer option of not downloading the linked files, because it can't be vouched for.

If a trustworthy person wrote the Powerpoint, and the files are in a secure location, and your communications cannot be intercepted, and no one has broken into the server and changed the files, then there's little problem.  However, there are multiple ways for someone malicious to take advantage.

Let's say that someone took over the server hosting those images.  Instead of serving the actual pictures, malware is delivered instead.

Let's say that someone intercepted the request, a man-in-the-middle attack.  Instead of serving the actual pictures, malware is delivered instead.

At the least, the host of those images (or other resources) will see a download of the files.   Let's say that traitor Tommy gave you this powerpoint, and it's got links to some images.  He knows you won't open the PowerPoint until you're in the conference room, so when he sees the images downloaded, he knows where you are and what you're doing.